# Problem when waking the computer from sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion dv6-2188la and when it wakes from sleep the monitor flashes (screen flickers), and every time it flashes (2 seconds) it returns me to the beginning of the password field making it almost impossible input the password.

Does anyone knows what causes this problem?

***More info: Intel Core i5-430M processor, Nvidia GeForce G 105M, 500GB HDD, 4GB RAM.***

Comment: I faced the same problem. Looks like bug in Windows OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Windows are you using?  If you have the install disc, you may want to reinstall...  Or, possibly, it's the screen resolution settings.  If you can log in and try to adjust these, then induce the flicker, see if that helps.